# Django импорт/экспорт паролей

Tags: django

Есть 2 системы. В одной пользователи регистрируются или создаются администратором. В другую эти пользователи должны импортироваться, но только с теми же данными включая пароли. Чтобы пользователи могли со своими паролями также входить и во второй системе после импорта.

Используя создание пользователя все равно создается новый пароль. Делаю так:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(id=row[0],
     username=username,
     email=email,
     password=[algoritm, iteration, salt, hesh],
     last_name=last_name,
     first_name=first_name)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно импортировать пользователя с теми же паролями.

Answer (score 0):

В поле `password` храниться уже зашифрованный пароль.

Так что достаточно просто сохранить его.

```
new_user.password = password
new_user.save()
```